# How can I use { within value(or path) with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

An example URL is this:

> api/v1/query?query=up{device="Device_1"}

where Device_1 is a @PathVariable

I test it with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/query?query=up{device=\"${device}\"}",
                method = RequestMethod.GET) String 
getLastPosting(@PathVariable("device") String device);
```

Response:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). content: Method Not Allowed

Any ideas about the right format?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/query/{device}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

What are your parameters plz clear.

Comment: do you absolutely need this format ? can't you use `api/v1/query?query=up&device=Device_1` for example? or even `api/v1/query/up/device/Device_1` ?

Answer (score 0):

This URL really looks very strange, also these braces would be a source of error in an URL, they would need to be replaced by `%7B` and `%7D`

I think you would be better off using a **simpler one** such as, for example:

```
api/v1/query?query=up&device=Device_1
```

And then declare your controller this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/query", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String getLastPosting(@RequestParam(value="query") String query, 
                             @RequestParam(value="device") String device) {
}
```

**Other options** would be using Unicode for curly braces (*but I don't recommend these*)

```
/api/v1/query=up%7Bdevice="Device_1"%7D

@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/{query}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLastPosting2(@PathVariable("query") String query){

  // query is query=up{device="Device_1"}
  // you would need to parse it to extract the device name

}
```

or

```
/api/v1/query=up%7Bdevice="Device_1"%7D

@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/query",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLastPosting3(@RequestParam("query") String query){

  // query is up{device="Device_1"}
  // you would need to parse it to extract the device name

}
```